# Convert Java Object with String Array as a Field to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a data model with that is a String[]. When I try to convert the model into JSONObject using the following code:

```
public class CheckList {
    private String id = "123";
    private String Q1 = "This is Question 1";
    private String[] Q2 = ["Part 1", Part 2"];

    public CheckList (String, id, String Q1, String[] Q2){
       ...
    }
}

CheckList checklist = new Checklist("123", "This is Question 1", ["Part 1", "Part 2"]

JSONObject test = new JSONObject(checklist);
```

the String[] is not being converted  properly. With the code above, I want a JSONObject look like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  Q1: This is Question 1,
  Q2: [Part 1, Part 2]
}
```

but I'm getting JSONObject like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  Q1: This is Question 1,
  Q2: [{"bytes":[{},{},{},{}],"empty":false},{"bytes":[{},{},{},{}],"empty":false}]
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) it's so efficient:

```
class CheckList {
    private String id = "123";
    private String Q1 = "This is Question 1";
    private String[] Q2 = {"Part 1", "Part 2"};
}


final String jsonObject = new Gson().toJson(new CheckList());

System.out.print(jsonObject);
```

Output :

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "Q1": "This is Question 1",
    "Q2": [
        "Part 1",
        "Part 2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `JsonArray` inside `CheckList` class to deserialize the array. However, if your implementation permits, you can use `Jackson` to convert the object inso `json`, it's easy to use and does not require bits like `JsonArray` to convert the object. Below is an example:

```
public class CheckList {
    private String id = "123";
    private String Q1 = "This is Question 1";
    private String[] Q2;

    public CheckList (String id, String Q1, String[] Q2){
       this.id = id;
       this.Q1 = Q1;
       this.Q2 = Q2;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQ1() {
        return Q1;
    }

    public void setQ1(String q1) {
        Q1 = q1;
    }

    public String[] getQ2() {
        return Q2;
    }

    public void setQ2(String[] q2) {
        Q2 = q2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        CheckList checklist = new CheckList("123", "This is Question 1", new String[]{"Part 1", "Part 2"});
        ObjectMapper objectMaapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(objectMaapper.writeValueAsString(checklist));

    }
}
```

[Here's](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.6) maven central URL for Jackson and [here's](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the entries step by step into the `JSONObject` and
convert the array first to an `ArrayList<String>`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Part 1");
list.add("Part 2");

JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
test.put("id", 123);
test.put("Q1","This is Question 1");
test.put("Q2", new JSONArray(list));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your solution. I'm looking more for a solution that will directly convert the model to json. My actual checklist model has 20 something fields so your solution is not as suitable for my use case.